# Animation not working with list item

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, animation

I am trying to show animation on list item click. Same animation work with button click but not with list item.
No exception printing on console.

Here is my code.

```
function animateButtons(clicked_btn_id){
    var circle = $('#' + clicked_btn_id + ' .circle');

    if (!circle.length) {
        $('#' + clicked_btn_id).append('<div class="circle"></div>');
            circle = $('#' + clicked_btn_id + ' .circle');
        }

        setTimeout(function(){
            circle.toggleClass('open');  
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
            //change image back
            circle.toggleClass('open');
        }, 300);
    }   
}

function clickedControlButton(clicked_btn_id){      
    animateButtons(clicked_btn_id);
}
```

Here is html code.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs list" id="myTab">
        <li>
            <img src="images/one.png" class="img-circle center-block img-reponsive" alt="one" onclick="clickedControlButton(this.id)" id="btnone">
            <p style="color:white;" class="index-footer-btn-text" id="oneText"> one </p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/two.png" class="img-circle center-block img-reponsive" alt="two" onclick="clickedControlButton(this.id)" id="btntwo">
            <p style="color:white;" class="index-footer-btn-text" id="twoText"> two </p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/three.png" class="img-circle center-block img-reponsive" alt="three" onclick="clickedControlButton(this.id)" id="btnthree">
            <p style="color:white;" class="index-footer-btn-text" id="threeText"> three </p>
        </li>          

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The `var circle = $('#' + clicked_btn_id + ' .circle');` seems to be returning `null` ?

Comment: 1. Please include the code of the button that is actually working, a demo will be nice .... 2. You are not binding the event to the list items instead you use the img tags which makes invalid your code appending a div inside the img.

Comment: @DaniP is correct!.. Indeed it is wring an `<div>` inside a `<img>` which is weired.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the listener to the list items and not to the images. Images do not support nested elements, meaning that you can't add any circles inside the image, so you need to add it inside the list and format it with CSS to look as you wish.

So:

- Remove the onclick event from the img elements
- Give the list elements some id's
- Attach the events to the list elements
- Format your circles using CSS

Here is a JSFiddle with the functionality you want to achieve:
https://jsfiddle.net/oz15hzsb/

Here is how to attach the listeners:

```
$('.nav-tabs li').click(function(){
    animateButtons($(this).attr('id'));
})
```